# How to frappe.get_all() with child table fields?

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I have a "Parcel" Doctype
Which have a “Parcel Content” Doctype as a child table.

If i do:

```
frappe.get_doc('Parcel', 'NAME')
```

I get the object with the child table in it, it works for a single object.

**But i need to get multiple objects with his child table fields**.

So i can't render a custom jinja template.

eg:

```
frappe.get_all('Parcel', fields=['fields_of_parent', 'content'], filters=[])
```

So this will get me the filtered objects with the child table.

Answer (score 2):

You have to query on the child table:

```
frappe.get_all("Parcel Content", 
    filters = dict(parent=parcel_name), 
    fields = [fields of child table])`
```

Comment: but this will only get you the parcel contents for one parcel, not for all parcels.

Answer (score -2):

Use list comprehension:

`[frappe.get_doc("Parcel", item.name).as_dict() for item in frappe.get_all("Parcel")]`

This will return all doctypes with their respective child table items. Not even need to query based on child table name.

Comment: This is a really awful idea from a database query perspective. It will do at least the same number of queries as the number of parcels. It could be done in a single query depending on what you want to achieve. The OP is not very clear though.